# Bootstrapper package not showing up in prerequisite menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, clickonce, bootstrapping

I am trying to create a bootstrapper package to add Crystal Reports 2011 to my application.  I have determined that the location should be c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper.  I added the package in the package folder but it does not show up in the prerequisites menu.  I have tried rebooting but it still does not show up.  I used the package that I downloaded from SAP called CRforVS_clickonce_13_0_3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should bundle the merge module for Crystal Reports 2011 inside your install package. If you include the merge modules they will simply be bundled into a single install.

(It didn't sound like there is a specific reason to bootstrap multiple MSI packages. The merge modules are an easy and reliable runtime deployment method.)